# How do I find the value for $ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} $ for which the following list of vectors is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following list of vectors
$ (sin^2(x), cos(2x), \lambda) $ as a subset of $ C(\mathbb{R}) $.
I've used the following identities to simplify $ cos(2x) $
$$ cos(2x) = cos^2(x) - sin^2(x) = 1 - 2sin^2(x) $$
Followed by the following setup
$$ a \cdot sin^2(x) + b \cdot (1 - 2sin^2(x)) + c \cdot \lambda = 0 $$
I tried $ a = 2, b = 1, c = 1 $ resulting in
$$ 2sin^2(x) + 1 - 2sin^2(x) + \lambda = 0 $$
$$ \lambda = -1 $$
I'm somewhat skeptical about my approach mainly because by setting $ a, b, c $ to any value I wanted, I could have changed $ c $ and $ \lambda $ to anything that's product results in -1. Is there something wrong with my approach, or am I a few steps short of a final solution? Thanks!

Comment: What's the subset $C(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I agree, $(\sin^2(x),\cos(2x),\lambda)$ is a linearly dependent set for all constant functions $\lambda$.

Comment: What you're noticing is that if three vectors are linearly dependent, then any nonzero multiples of them are also linearly dependent.

Comment: I'm not sure @GuillemusCallelus what you mean by what the subset $ C(\mathbb{R}) $ is. Isn't $ (sin^2(x), cos(2x), \lambda) $ the subset for this problem?

Comment: @Ian am I lacking something fundamental here? Is the situation I'm afraid of where $ c $ and $ \lambda $ can be anything not an issue here?

Comment: @SeanTakafuji At least in the problem as stated, $(\sin^2(x),\cos(2x),\lambda)$ is a linearly dependent set for any constant function $\lambda$. So if you expected uniqueness of $\lambda$ for some reason, then either you've misunderstood the problem, or else you've presented the problem to us incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_{0}$ be the function $f_{0}(x), \forall x\in \mathbb{R}; \{\sin^{2}x,\cos(2x),k\}$
$$a\sin^{2}x+b\cos(2x)+ck\equiv f_{0}\rightarrow a\sin^{2}x+b(1-2\sin^{2}x)+ck\equiv f_{0}$$
$$\rightarrow (a-2b)\sin^{2}x+(b+ck)\equiv f_{0}\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             a=2b \\
             \\ b+ck=0
             \end{array}
   \right.\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             a=2b \\
             \\ c=-\frac{b}{k}
             \end{array}
   \right.\rightarrow \text{Okay}\hspace{2mm}\forall k\neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let be $a,b$ and $c$ are constats such that

$$a\sin^2x + b \cos2x + c \lambda = 0$$
$\forall x \in R$. In particular, the above equation is true for $x = 0, x = \pi/2$ and $x = 3\pi/2$, getting the equations set

$$b + c\lambda = 0$$
$$a - b + c\lambda = 0$$
$$-b + c\lambda = 0$$
solving the equations, we has that $a = 0, b = 0$ and $c\lambda = 0$. Therefore, o set of functions is L.I if, and if,  $\lambda \neq 0$